Cors confict with 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'
I have a Node.js application with a React front-end. I'm working on this application in Project IDX. The CORS configuration is as follows:
backend:
app.use(cors({
   origin: 'https://5173-url-front-idx.dev',
   credentials: true
}));

front:
const instance = axios.create({
   baseURL: 'https://3000-url-backend-idx.dev',
   withCredentials: true
});

This configuration works without any issues locally, but it doesn't work in IDX. When I check the browser console, it says the error is 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', expecting a true but receiving an empty string (' '). This doesn't make sense because, as seen in the code, true is being sent.
